# graph not showing in horizontalscrollview android

Tags: android, xaml, android-layout, layout, xamarin.android

i am microcharts.droid.ChartView in xamarin to make a line graph, and i want it to be horizontal scroll able, but by using following code graph is not showing up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#444444">
    <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/profilepicimageview"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepic"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/profilepicimageview"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/txtHomeFullName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="12500"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/HomeUserTextViewScore"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewStarHome"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/HomeUserTextViewScore" />
    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="15dp"
        android:minHeight="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageViewStarHome"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarHome"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
  <HorizontalScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp">
      <TextView
          android:text="WELCOME TO PERKIT"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          android:gravity="center"

          android:background="#302f2f"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:id="@+id/textViewWelcomeToPerkit" />
      <microcharts.droid.ChartView
          android:id="@+id/chartView"

          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linebtn"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#444444"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/rewardDisabled"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:id="@+id/btnHomeReward" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/leaderDisabled"
            android:id="@+id/btnHomeTournaments"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/settingsDisabled"
            android:id="@+id/btnHomeSettings"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/homeEnabled"
            android:id="@+id/btnHomeHome"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbuttonEnabled" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="Loading.."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/txtLoadingTextHome"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#8889" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i want to make the graph horizontal scroll able. to show on layout.
thanks. how can i achieve it in android.i am developing the app in xamarin android. is there any other good library to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a fixed layout_width to the chartView